# Laravel: Count through two Models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables, settlements table hasMany add_members table and ciphers table hasMany add_members table. In Settlement and Cipher Model I put function:

```
public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AddMember');
    }
```

so now, when I need count how many rows in add_members table I have but with reon_id in settlements table I did like this:

```
$first_count = Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
  ->with('members')
  ->where('reon_id', '1')
  ->count();
```

and that working, but now I need second count which also counting add_members rows with reon_id == 1 in settlements table but woth one more relationships where cipher == 0 in ciphers table. If I do with belongsTo relationship through AddMember Model I'm getting error:

(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reon_id' in 'where clause'

```
$second_count = Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
      ->with('members')
      ->where('reon_id', '1')
      ->Cipher::with('members')
      ->where('cipher', '0')
      ->count();
```

I know that this second is wrong but I don't know hot to get with reon_id == 1 in Settlement model and cipher == 0 in Cipher model...

Answer (score 0):

Laravel relation table query

```
$first_count = Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
  ->with(['members', function ($q) {
        $q->where('reon_id', 1);
}])->get();
```

or

```
$first_count = Settlement::with('members')->where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
  ->whereHas('members', function ($q) {
        $q->where('reon_id', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: No, I don't need that. I edited question because maybe I was't clear in a first place. I need $second_count variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way, so eloquent know which column is in which table?

```
$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
  $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%'); 
}])->get();
```

Or type additional Info about columns like this:

```
App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();
```

More in laravel docs

Comment: I edited question because maybe I was't clear in a first place. I need $second_count variable.